# Does D always get the special power of the dragon they vanquish?

Tags: unlimited-fafnir

In the series, it is shown Yuu learns how to use antigravity, and Mitsuki can make antimatter.

Since the anime ends just after they defeat Basilisk, did any of them learned to use catastrophe?

Does it happen to the other dragons they kill in the Light Novel?